# How to make Query Builder By Update Join 2 Tables In The Phalcon

Tags: mysql, api, phalcon

I want to make QueryBuilder on the Update Join 2 Tables. But I don't know sintaks it. Please Write codes to me about how to make it. I give example query of the following below:

```
    UPDATE Teachers
    INNER JOIN Education
    ON Education.id=Teachers.id
    SET
        Teachers.userid=:userid:,
        Teachers.fullname=:fullname:,
        Teachers.birthday=:birthday:,
        Teachers.gender=:gender:,
        Teachers.currentjob=:currentjob:,
        Education.primaryschool=:primaryschool:,
        Education.juniorhighschool=:juniorhighschool:,
        Education.seniorhighschool=:seniorhighschool:,
    WHERE Teachers.id=:id:
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know PHQL doesn't allow update like this. When you write PHQL update query in phalcon it'as actually making SELECT query, and calling update method to make sure all the events, validation etc are fired for the models. With joins this is obviously a problem how to exactly do it, beacause you might join some model which doesn't have relations provided.

Phalcon just don't support JOINS with UPDATE, you need to use raw query.